# How do i get my google login token to authorize users when sending get request?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

How do I pull tokens from the request headers to authorize get requests when I am using google login for my react node project, most of the methods i could find and I knew are depreciated? I tried

```
req.header.authorization.split()[1]
```

I kept getting undefined.